# PHP Array Unintentionally Turning into Int

Tags: php

I might be searching incorrectly but I cannot find a solution to my issue. I have an empty `array` created for values in a database. Each row should `push` a value to the `array` but after the first element my array becomes an integer.

```php
if ($num_rows > 0){
    $dates = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   
        var_dump($dates);
        $dates = array_push($dates, $row['date']);
    }
}
```

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

**EDIT** the `date` field of my db is a `varchar`

Comment: `array_push` *Returns the new number of elements in the array.* (from [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   
    var_dump($dates);
    array_push($dates, $row['date']);
}
```

without assigning result. Because [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) works with array **by reference**. And returns not **new array** but:

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.